# sherlocklistfragment not showing list

Tags: java, android, sqlite, actionbarsherlock

Hey im trying to make a ListView with data from my SQLite database. Right now I have a layout called tricks_list where im displaying an edittext field and a searchbutton. Beneath those I have my ListView where I want trick_names placed.
The code runs but instead of showing a list, there is just a spinner spinning forever.
Anyone know what's wrong? 
This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="80" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java:

```
public class TrickListTab extends SherlockListFragment implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private Fragment mFragment;
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
public ListView lv;
public SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.tricks_list);

}

public void getTricks(View view) {
    try {

        db.open();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    Cursor tricks = db.getTrick_name();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tricks,
            new String[] { "trick_name" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
}
```

And here is the Cursor:

```
public Cursor getTrick_name() {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT trick_name FROM Tricks_list",
            null);
}
```

Comment: where you are calling `getTricks` method ? if you call it then probably you get exception because of `DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());` line.so just declare `DBAdapter db` at class level field and initialize it in `getTricks` method or in `onCreate` method

Comment: I dont even need the method. Can I have the code placed inside my onCreate? Or would that be a bad idea?

Comment: ur code looking fine currently if you move all code inside onCreate then maybe you get issue in managing when you have 1000's number of lines in onCreate so always use methods or helper classes instead of  doing inline code

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the DBAdapter in (or after) the onCreate() method.

```
DBAdapter db;
public ListView lv;
public SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.tricks_list);

}
```

Comment: I've changed my code accordingly, but the problem stays the same. The spinner just spins around. Seems like it doesnt get the items from my database.